# How to UI test a checkbox button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a checkbox button which is a custom button, I am changing button image to selected and unselected on button click.

I need to UI test this element, how do I do that?

I tried to get the element using the image name but it didn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the checkbox is selected, add the `selected` accessibility trait. Then, in your UI test, check the element's `isSelected` property.

```
// App code
imageView.accessibilityTraits = imageView.accessibilityTraits.union([.selected])

// Test code
XCTAssertTrue(checkboxElement.isSelected)
```

Remember to add logic to remove the `selected` trait when the checkbox is unselected.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the solution

Override the `accessibilityLabel` of the button and return `selected`/`deslected` based on button's state.

Then in UITest just check the `accessibilityLabel`.

For visual state test you can have snapshot test.